# Alternatingly remove each character from a string returning the rest as one per loop

Tags: c#, string, loops

Example input `string` is `"12345"` the result should be: `"2345, 1345, 1245, 1235, 1234"`. I have tried `Substring` and `Remove`  alone and in combinations with halfway success. I would prefer to not have to manually put & manipulate the string's elements in a list/array, and to keep the solution within basic String operations, if at all possible. This was my latest attempt:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string message = "12345"; // length: 5
        string removed; int i = 0;
        
        removed = message.Substring(i+1); Console.WriteLine("1: " + removed);

        for(i = 2; i < message.Length; i++) {
            removed = message.Substring(i);
        
            Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + removed);
        }

        removed = message.Substring(i); 
        
        Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + removed);
    }
}
```

@Mureinik   Thank you for your solution. I chose it for its simplicity.

I also realized going through it that I may have messed up my index iteration for `Remove` the first time I tired using it; that's why it kept throwing the exceptions.

I have decided to leave my code here as reference for my explanation and because the solution I chose looks different.

Comment: You could try using [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_) instead of `Substring`

Comment: @devNull As I wrote in the description, I tried it but either it removed everything starting after the given index or when I gave it a range it threw out of order exceptions. I couldn't do it, but if you know how to can you please show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a new `StringBuilder` in every iteration of the loop, and use it to remove a character:

```
string message = "12345"; // length: 5
for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; ++i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
    sb.Remove(i, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

Comment: Why do this over `Remove`ing from the string directly?

Comment: @mjwills  I don't know. As I answered to devNull's short question above, I tried and it either deleted everything from the given index onward or when I specified the range it threw out of order exceptions. Though I will welcome your solution too if you post it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do it either with a help of `Remove`:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Removes(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    yield break;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
    yield return value.Remove(i, 1);
}
```

Or `Substring` (a bit less efficient):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Removes(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    yield break;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
    yield return value.Substring(0, i) + value.Substring(i + 1);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Removes("12345")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
2345, 1345, 1245, 1235, 1234
```